Should std::span be passed by value or const reference?
Should std::span be passed by value or const reference? What are the implications of either?
void MyFunction(std::span s);
// or
void MyFunction(const std::span& s);


Technically the const reference would be smaller, right? https://godbolt.org/z/xach48qMx

std::span is very lightweight (typically a pointer and a size even if the span is dynamic), you can pass it by value.

It's similar to a string_view. It should be passed by value.

View type usually pass by value like string_view.

This post has some answers explaining why views should be passed by value. The same reasons hold for std::span.

only by value. All this std::string_view std::span are just new fancy version of reference (wrapped pointers) and should be treated like that.

Technically the const reference would be smaller, right? Sort of.  What the godbolt code is measuring is the sizeof the span, versus the sizeof a pointer (not a reference).  A reference as a parameter is probably implemented as a pointer — but may be optimized away entirely.  And neglects to account for the cost of the (probably) pointer and the cost of the object being pointed to, and the cost of indirection.  One prominent compiler designer (Chris Lattner) lamented that using references for parameters or return variables is a premature optimization. Profile and measure.
